# Move div contents on mouseover of container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I'm working on a concept of a movable map and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or provide some examples of this already happening:

Issue:
I have a map that is contained in a div, the div is smaller than the full map. 
What I want to achieve is for the map to move when a person rolls over the container div. 
And of course be able to control where the map should stop moving by setting some type of boundary.
Think Google Maps but by mouse movement and containment (without a user having to click to move the map).

Thanks for anyones help!

Comment: how do I code my own operating system.. ?

Comment: You can take a look at this website [link](http://www.ormanclark.com).Click on -work link

Comment: Thanks for the link @anu. @jAndy - If i could down rank comments then I would.

Answer (score 0):

i could not perfectly figure out what you are looking for but i guess you need to look for jQuery scroll and mousewheel plugins. If you can be a little more elaborative we can figure that out.

Comment: I'll try to elaborate more! - I have a div, lets say 400x400 which is the container/parent for another div which is 800x800 which has an image of a map. At any give time you can only see a 400x400 portion of the map. What I want to do is have where the user doesn't have to click the map and drag it to see other parts of the map. The user shouldn't have to physically click anything with in that 400x400 block to make the map move. The mouse movement within the div should control the movement of the map. Does that help clarify it some?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plug-in in my application. This might be helpful